# System.Type && TypeHandle->MethodTable-> EEClass

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, clr

I have a problem: I cannot understand which entities described in topic  title,  CLR uses to provide type safety. Read ["`TypeHandle->MethodTable-> EEClass`"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) if you don't understand what I mean.
 At first I will describe how I understand these concepts, and with pleasure will wait from you that you correct me and provide some additional information which sheds some light on this. 

So on: I imagine that "`TypeHandle->MethodTable-> EEClass` CLT creates it before the time when the application executes its first line of code  and use this entity for further providing type safety and  casting, Polymorphism (virtual functions calls).
 On the other end System.Type is an instance which will be created at our request via `GetType()` of `typeof()`.

 So I'm confused, `System.Type && TypeHandle->MethodTable-> EEClass` perform the same role but are separated into different entities.

Comment: The article gives you look into the CLR internals.  Where types are stored in C++ data structures.  Very different from the managed Type class that any managed code can use.  But of course with the same kind of info for a type.  Type safety is enforced by the verifier built into the jitter.

Comment: @Hans Passant So, System.Type instance  builds based on metadata tables or on MethodTable->EEClass that CLR loaded before application start